# Not getting expected output for 2D Matrix calculation

Tags: python, list

I am not getting expected output with the below given function:

```
# Input: matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
# Output: [[7,4,1],[8,5,2],[9,6,3]]

def rotate(matrix):
    master_lst = [[]]*len(matrix)
    
    for val in matrix:
        for i, v in enumerate(val):
            master_lst[i].insert(0, v)
            #print(f"master_lst[{i}].insert(0, {v})")
    
    return master_lst

matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
rotate(matrix)
```

Getting wrong output -

```
[[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
 [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]]
```

If I run these commands directly, then I get the expected output:

```
master_lst = [[], [], []]
master_lst[0].insert(0, 1)
master_lst[1].insert(0, 2)
master_lst[2].insert(0, 3)
master_lst[0].insert(0, 4)
master_lst[1].insert(0, 5)
master_lst[2].insert(0, 6)
master_lst[0].insert(0, 7)
master_lst[1].insert(0, 8)
master_lst[2].insert(0, 9)
master_lst
```

Please help me in understanding the reasoning behind this.

Comment: don't use `[[]]*number`, it does not give unique lists, use `[ [] for _ in range(number)]`

Comment: `[[]]*len(matrix)` gives you 3 references to the **same** list.

Comment: why use `insert` when `append` is more what you want to do

Comment: @riov8 - Thank you so much for helping. Now I understood the reason behind the scene. :) As I'm trying to traverse through the input matrix, I'm trying to make sure new items get added at the start of the sub-lists (of new nested list) and rest moves one step right as is expected.

Comment: @mark-tolonen - Thank you so much for helping. Now I understood the reason behind the scene. :)